# Will focusing on statistics experience be beneficial for math job applications?

Tags: mathematics, cv, statistics

I've had a PhD in pure mathematics for the last 5 years, and have found several good positions, including a tenure track position I amicably left for personal reasons.

However, the job market is getting pretty tight in mathematics for tenure track positions.

I just recently have one year of statistics teaching experience (the most recent year). While interviewing for my current (temporary) position at a small liberal arts college, some of the interviewers were highly interested in my statistics experience, and I was told that statistics experience was essentially a requirement for the position.

> I'll have taught for a second year, when I apply in the fall.
>
> Is this a valuable experience that I should emphasize in my resume
> (compared to my  several years of calculus/algebra/linear algebra
> teaching)? If so, how can I  effectively highlight it?

I can't tell if it was just a fluke (like the occasional combined math/comp sci positions), or a general rule that those with statistics expertise are preferable at liberal arts colleges.

Comment: I can't comment on academic jobs, but from my experience, knowledge in statistics is extremely beneficial if you ever want to get a job outside of academia. So my advice would be that pointing out expertise in statistics will never harm you, and will often help you, so it's worth pointing out. Worst case scenario is they just think nothing of it.